# How do I Mercurial for downloading source from http://kenai.com?

Tags: mercurial

How do I download a source code using Mercurial? I am interested to get the source from http://kenai.com/projects/javaee-patterns/sources/hg/show/AOPandJavaEE . I installed Mercurial ,and I tried `hg clone https://hg.kenai.com/hg/javaee-patterns~hg` but I got the following error:

```
abort: error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not pr
operly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cloning successfully for me:

```
$ hg clone https://hg.kenai.com/hg/javaee-patterns~hg
warning: hg.kenai.com certificate with fingerprint 9c:f6:c3:1f:14:bc:98:82:de:2a:5b:6e:d2:ce:61:5d:95:e1:65:a5 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
destination directory: javaee-patterns~hg
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 465 changesets with 3698 changes to 2360 files (+1 heads)
updating to branch default
2064 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Your error message makes it look like you're having a network connection failure, but that's more likely related to your internet connection than theirs.

You could try doing a `hg init` followed by a `hg pull -r 1 https://hg.kenai.com/hg/javaee-patterns~hg` which pulls only the first changeset, but that would only help if you were timing out while downloading -- you're timing out while initially connecting.

It looks like if you create an account and login they'll show you a ssh URL which is likely more robust.

Comment: Ry4an, thanks. You are right. I was able to downloaded the code from my personal computer.